# Log statement during unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am currently starting to unit test my android application. I am having problems when the unit test exercise code that has log statements in it. Here is a specific case. I have a class called ServiceManager that has a `setSystemPause()` and a `getSystemPause()` method. I just want a simple unit test that exercise that logic

ServiceManager class:

```
 public class ServiceManager implements IServiceManager {

    private final static String TAG = "ServiceManager";

    private boolean mSystemPauseStatus = false;

    public boolean getSystemPause () {
        Log.i ("TAG", "getSystemPause: " + mSystemPauseStatus);
        return mSystemPauseStatus;
    }

    public void setSystemPause (boolean pauseStatus){
        Log.i ("TAG", "setSystemPause: " + pauseStatus);
        mSystemPauseStatus = pauseStatus;
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
public class ServiceManagerTest {

    @Test
    public void testSystemPause() throws Exception {
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager();

        serviceManager.setSystemPause(false);
        assert (! serviceManager.getSystemPause());

        serviceManager.setSystemPause(true);
        assert (serviceManager.getSystemPause());
    }
}
```

The problem are the "Log.i" statements in my code. That causes the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method i in android.util.Log not mocked.
```

I understand what is happening, during unit test the android.jar library that is used does not contain the real code and I need to mock that call to "Log.i".

But the code base that I am going to test contains a lot of Log statements. I don't want to mock each usage of the Log facility.

My question is how do people do unit testing in Android while having Log statements in their code. Is there another log facility that I can use in my code instead of the Log class.

I also read the page here:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

They suggest doing this in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

I don't want to resort to that because I just want the Log to appear. I want to properly mock all other facilities I will use in Android.

Answer (score 0):

But will the Log statement affect the outcome of your unit tests? Problem is that `Log` is an Android-specific class, and can't be used as part of a JUnit 4 test as it's not part of the Java JDK. If you need `Log` statements to work as intended, either mock the behaviour out with Mockito, use `returnDefaultValues = true`, or run the test as a [Connected Android Test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) (`/androidTest` folder instead of `/test`).

I personally use `returnDefaultValues = true` as you mention as Logging is something I'm not usually interested in when Unit Testing, only when I'm trying to track down specific bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a *package level* method in `ServiceManager` class which calls `Log.i` method.

```
public class ServiceManager implements IServiceManager {

private final static String TAG = "ServiceManager";

private boolean mSystemPauseStatus = false;

public boolean getSystemPause () {
    log("TAG", "getSystemPause: " + pauseStmSystemPauseStatusatus);
    return mSystemPauseStatus;
}

public void setSystemPause (boolean pauseStatus){
    log("TAG", "setSystemPause: " + pauseStatus);
    mSystemPauseStatus = pauseStatus;
}

void log(String tag, String message) {
    Log.i (tag, message);
}
```

Then you can override this method in `ServiceManagerTest` to provide no implementation.

```
public class ServiceManagerTest {

@Test
public void testSystemPause() throws Exception {
    ServiceManager serviceManager = createServiceManager();

    serviceManager.setSystemPause(false);
    assert (! serviceManager.getSystemPause());

    serviceManager.setSystemPause(true);
    assert (serviceManager.getSystemPause());
}

private ServiceManager createServiceManager() {
  return new ServiceManager() {
     @Override
     void log(String tag, String message) {
       //Do nothing or you could test that this method was called.
     }
  }
}
}
```